# Password.h and keypad.h change pass sketch for Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

I have a fixed password. If letter "D" is pressed on the keyboard and the correct password is entered, the fixed password will be then changed. This newly entered password is now the correct password, until the user decides again to change password. It is not working. **How to fix it?**

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Password.h>

const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //four columns

const char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
    {'1','2','3','A'},
    {'4','5','6','B'},
    {'7','8','9','C'},
    {'*','0','#','D'}
  };
const byte rowPins[ROWS] = {9,8,7,6};
const byte colPins[COLS] = {5,4,3,2};

Keypad    keypad { makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS };
Password passwd = Password("123A4");
char passwd2;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  char key = keypad.getKey();
   if (key != NO_KEY){
      delay(60); 
      switch (key){
      case 'D': changepasswd(); break; 
      case '*': checkpasswd(); break;
      case '#': passwd.reset(); break;
     default: passwd.append(key);
      }
   }
}


void checkpasswd() {

  Serial.print(passwd2);

   if (passwd.evaluate()){
      Serial.println(" OK.");
   } else {
      Serial.println(" Wrong password!");
   } 
   passwd.reset();
}

void changepasswd() {
  char key = keypad.getKey();
      delay(60); 
      Serial.print(key);
      passwd2 += key;
      passwd.set(passwd2);

   Serial.print("Password changed to ");
   Serial.println(passwd2);

}
```

Comment: `It is not working` is not a useful description  of what happens ... please provide a description of what actually happens

Comment: You don't have and kind of loop in `changepasswd()` to get more than one character into the password. Also you are just using the value from `geKey()` without first checking, if there was really a valid key pressed after the change was initiated. Work out the logic of your functions.

Comment: @jsotola The password is not changing. That is the description. The part of entering the default "123A4" is working and the OK message is appearing. If you enter an invalid code, it says "Wrong password". So far so good. But when it comes to changing the password via keyboard, it says "Passord changed to " and show nothing. If you enter the new password, it says "Wrong password"... if you enter the default password, it says "Wrong password".

Comment: @chrisl I have been working on this the whole week. I cannot work out the logic of my functions by myself at this point. This code is the best I could do and that's why I am asking for help to fix it, because I can no longer go further.

Comment: @LuizVaughan, `if you enter the default password, it says "Wrong password"` .... so, why do you say that the password is not changing? .... from what you said, it is changing .... you just do not know what it changes to ..... i suggest that  you spend time finding out what the new password is, and change your code so that it saves the actual password that you want

Comment: **per1234; VE7JRO, sempaiscuba, MatsK** and **gre_gor**. Sorry, but only you guys think this post was unclear. Problem was well understood and, by the way, solved many hours before you all "put on hold".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of your function is garbled:

1. **Function `checkpasswd()`**: Most of the function is ok, but you don't need to send `passwd2` through Serial, since it doesn't have anything to do with this function. You only use the variable for setting a new password. You can ditch this print statement.
2. **Function `changepasswd()`**: Here lies the problem. Most likely `getKey()` returns `NO_KEY` here, which is defined as the null character. So, when outputting it to Serial, you don't see anything there (The null character marks the end of a string in C/C++). You set the password to be the null character, which cannot every be inputted by the user. Also there lies another pitfall: The [Arduino Playground Site](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Password) for the `Password` library states for the `set()` function:

   > Warning: The new password should be a global variable (not a local
   >   function variable) as this function copies a pointer to the new
   >   password into the library, not a copy of the password.

Since the `key` variable is only local, after the function the `Password` library has it's internal pointer pointing to a now freed memory space. At some other point in the program this space might be written again, effectively changing to password to something else.

And lastly the function does not contain any loop, so only 1 character will be inputted and the newly set password can only be 1 character long. The buffer variable `passwd2` is of type `char`, so also only 1 character. What you really need there is a `char []` (character array).

Here is a bit of code (not tested), that should implement this correctly:

```
char passwd2[6]=""; //global buffer for new password
                    // 6 bytes, because a C string has to end with the null character

void changepasswd(){
    for(byte i=0;i<5;i++){
        char key = NO_KEY;
        while(key == NO_KEY || key=='*' || key=='#' || key=='D') key = keypad.getKey();
        passwd2[i] = key;
        delay(60);
    }
    passwd2[5] = '\0'; //ensure correct string ending
    passwd.set(passwd2);
}
```

Note the following points:

- This implementation blocks the programs execution, until a full valid password has been typed. It will ignore all invalid characters, that you use for other purposes (`#`, `*` and `D`).
- The `passwd.set(passwd2)` is actually only necessary the first time, we change the password, to let the `Password` object have a pointer to our buffer. After that we technically can change the password directly in the buffer, without calling the `set()` function. I included it here for readability and making the code a bit more fail prove (against wrong futher coding).
- This is hardcoded to accept only 5-digit passwords. If you want passwords with arbitrary length, you can start programming from this basis.
- Debouncing buttons with a simple `delay()` may be not enough at some point. But as I understand the source code of the `Keypad` library, it also includes code for debouncing, by only checking every 10ms for a changed button and returning `NO_KEY` everytime else.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time to make corrections and for your detailed explanations. Your suggestion has been tested and is fully working. Kind regards!